# TASM. Сравнение элементов массива

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

Ассемблером занимаюсь около месяца и есть задание: определить у скольких чисел массива равные соседи, столкнулся с такой проблемой, что элементы сравниваются не правильно, не могу понять почему.

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
  mass db 1,7,3,5,3,5,4,5,4
  res dw ?
.code
begin:
  mov cx, 10
  lea si, mass
  xor ax, ax
  xor bx, bx
testt:
  inc si
  mov ax, [si-1]
  mov bx, [si+1]
  cmp ax, bx
  je plus
plus: inc res
  xor ax, ax
  xor bx, bx
  loop testt
end begin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя происходит выход за пределы массива, потому что когда si будет равен 7, он будет указывать на последнюю цифру 4, а команда

```
mov bx, [si+1]
```

уже указывает за пределы границ твоего массива. Следовательно цикл тебе надо уменьшить до 7.

```
mov cx, 7
```

На сколько я помню в трубо-ассемблере, есть хороший отладчик, в котором можно пробежаться по твоему коду и посмотреть все состояния регистров в момент отладки. Пользуйся им, в основном отладчик - это хорошее средство для понимания того, как работает твой код!